# Hadoop command not found

Tags: java, hadoop

I have installed and configured hadoop in a linux machine .Now i am trying to run a sample MR job.I have started the hadoop via the command /usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh and the output is

```
namenode running as process 7876. Stop it first.
localhost: datanode running as process 8083. Stop it first.
localhost: secondarynamenode running as process 8304. Stop it first.
jobtracker running as process 8398. Stop it first.
localhost: tasktracker running as process 8612. Stop it first.
```

so i think that my hadoop is configured successfully.But when i am tryinh to run below command it is giving

```
jeet@jeet-Vostro-2520:~$ hadoop fs -put gettysburg.txt /user/jeet/getty/gettysburg.txt
hadoop: command not found
```

i am new in hadoop.somebody please help .I am also posting the screenshot of what i am trying[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As it seems from your commands history, you can replace `hadoop` by `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop` and it should help.

---

If you want to use `hadoop` command without specifying the full path to it, you can edit `~/.bashrc` file and add the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/
```

Then you need to reopen your terminal.

Comment: you mean this jeet@jeet-Vostro-2520:~$ usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put gettysburg.txt /user/jeet/getty/gettysburg.txt  but this is returning bash: usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: No such file or directory

Comment: you don't need to open your terminal, you can write `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Actually, it should be export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop

Answer (score 7):

edit `PATH` variable, if you want to be able to invoke hadoop without specifying full path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/
```

if you want it for each bash profile then edit `~/.bash_profile` to include this

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, and  this worked for me

I configured path variable in.bashrc.

export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop

export PATH= $PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

Sometime restarting your machine can resolve the issue ,only if you have configured everything correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd ~

vi .bashrc

export PATH=$PATH:<hadoop installation path>
```

for example replace `<hadoop installation path>` by `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/`

Comment: I tried this but still not able to run any hadoop commands... Any other suggestions?

Comment: did you restart your terminal session?

Answer (score 0):

once echo your path ,if your path hasn't set ,then go to your .bashrc file

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

and add folliwing in that.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are logged into the particular user, whose .bashrc file has got this entry

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/

Assuming that your hadoop setup is lying at /usr/local

Example You have set the .bashrc file for user hadoopuser in /home/hadoopuser/.bashrc, then you should be logged in as hadoop user only and not as any other user.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop command not found?

put this 3 commands at the end of ~/.bashrc file
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/Work/hadoop-1.2.1

export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH*

java-8-openjdk-amd64 - put your folder name

hadoop-1.2.1 - put your folder name

save the file and use below command
source ~/.bashrc

or simply close the terminal and open it again