# Hadoop cannot run

Tags: hadoop

I just download hadoop and install it, see my terminal output below:

```
steven81@steven81-HP:/usr/local/hadoop-3.0.3/bin$ ls -l
total 844
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81 366296 6月   1 01:25 container-executor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81   8261 6月   1 01:13 hadoop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81  10944 6月   1 01:13 hadoop.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81  10850 6月   1 01:15 hdfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81   8081 6月   1 01:15 hdfs.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81   5704 6月   1 01:27 mapred
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81   6311 6月   1 01:27 mapred.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81 403256 6月   1 01:25 test-container-executor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81  10721 6月   1 01:25 yarn
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steven81 steven81  12840 6月   1 01:25 yarn.cmd

steven81@steven81-HP:/usr/local/hadoop-3.0.3/bin$ hadoop
hadoop: command not found
```

So why I get the error that indicates hadoop command not found?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369102/hadoop-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either edit your PATH variable to include the bin directory there

Otherwise, you must run the command from that directory exactly as `./hadoop`

Some examples will show `./bin/hadoop`, which as an absolute path, translates to `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop`